# Laravel 5.8 Hace migraciones pero luego no conecta a la base de datos

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql, docker

Hola tengo un problema con la conexión a mi base de datos.

Nota: La base de datos de postgres esta en un contenedor docker.

En la configuración del archivo .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=192.168.99.100
DB_PORT=32776
DB_DATABASE=admin
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Si en la linea de comando escribo: php artisan migrate y se ejecuta correctamente, crea las tablas dentro de la base de datos.

Ahora trato de conectarme de la siguiente manera:

En web.php

```
Route::get('lista_nombres', 'ListadoController@nombres') ;
```

En ListadoController.php

Declaro:

```
use App\Personas;
```

La función:

```
    public function nombres() {
         $lista = Personas::orderBy('apellido', 'asc')->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->get();
         return $lista ;
    }
```

Mi problema es que ahora trato de leer una de las tablas y me da el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión.\r\n

No entiendo que me falta, la migración agrega tabla las quita, o sea, puedo ejecutar incluso el rollback y crear tablas de prueba, pero al tratar de leer los registros no me deja.

¿Alguna luz sobre el camino?

Comment: no estarás ejecutando el comando artisan por ssh? por q veo q la base de datos no es localhost , cuéntanos como tienes montado el sistema. ¿Has probado a borrar la cache del config, el usuario de la BD tiene todos los permisos?

Comment: Hola, Mi Laravel corre en localhost, y mi postgres corre en un docker. Todo en mi equipo, nada remoto.

Comment: En este momento me doy cuenta, que esta tomando la configuración del archivo /config/database.php, o sea, para algunas cosas esta tomando los valores de .env y para otras la de /config/database.php puse los valores de conexión también en el archivo database.php y ahora se conecta sin problemas.

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema, corte la publicación en el servidor, inicié nuevamente php artisan serve y funcionó

Comment: Que malo de mi pare no actualizar esta pregunta, le pido disculpas a todos. La verdad que en ese momento no encontraba solución. Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera: Cree un nuevo proyecto de laravel y pase las rutas, los modelos, las vistas y controladores al nuevo proyecto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Quizá tengas que dar permisos de postgres a tu usuario.

Intenta lo siguiente:

Tendras que ir a la dirección de tu postgres y buscar el archivo **pg_hba.conf**, en windows esta en `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data` y en linux creo que esta en: `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/`, dependiendo de tu version de postgres.

Una vez encontrado el archivo debemos de editarla, busca algo parecido a esto:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Generalmente esta al final del documento.

Entonces debes de agregar la dirección ip de la maquina desde la cual quieres acceder a tu base de datos, de esta forma:

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.107/32            md5
```

En caso querer dar los permisos de acceso a todos los usuarios utiliza:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Guardas el archivo y ya esta.

Existen mas metodos de conexion, puedes leerlos [aqui](https://codigobinariovzla.wordpress.com/2019/02/21/dar-permisos-a-ips-especificas-en-postgresql-desde-linux/)

Comment: Hola Shassain, gracias por tu respuesta. El problema lo resolvi creando un nuevo proyecto de laravel y migrando todo al nuevo proyecto. Así que en mi caso, creo que era un problema de configuración de ese proyecto de laravel. Nuevamente gracias por tu tiempo, saludos.